# is it possible to see when I press the down arrow on a Data Grid in C# WPF how to tie a event to that?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

is it possible to see when I press the down arrow on a Data Grid in C# WPF how to tie a event to that?

For example there is events like Loaded, OnClick etc for DataGrids.. But how can i see if the user has clicked the down arrow that is on the vertical scroll bar to the right of the datagrid?

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this to your XAML `scrollViewer.ScrollChanged="dataGrid_ScrollChanged"`

then something like this in code behind

```
private void dataGrid_ScrollChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Controls.ScrollChangedEventArgs args = (System.Windows.Controls.ScrollChangedEventArgs)e;
            if (args.VerticalChange > 0)
            {
                //scrolled down
            }
            else if (args.VerticalChange < 0)
            {
                //scrolled up
            }
            else
            {
                //who knows what happened
                //probably just loading the grid
            }

        }
```